# I am getting 'Given String is empty or null' error in Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
LoginButton(
          onPressed: () {
            signUp();
            final user = Profiles(
              id: id.v1(),
              email: email.text.trim(),
              gender: selectedGender == 1 ? 'Erkek' : 'Kadın',
              name: name.text.trim(),
              username: username.text.trim(),
            );

            createUser(user);
          }, // signUp,
        ),
```

**I am trying to register the user in Firebase Authentication with the signUp() function when the button is pressed, and register the information in the Firestore with the createUser() function.**

```
  Future signUp() async {
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email.text.trim(),
        password: password.text.trim(),
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
  }

  Future createUser(Profiles profile) async {
    final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('profiles').doc();
    profile.id = docUser.id;

    final json = profile.toJson();
    await docUser.set(json);
  }
```

**The Profiles class I created.**

```
    class Profiles {
  String id;
  final String name;
  final String username;
  final String gender;
  final String email;

  Profiles(
      {required this.id,
      required this.email,
      required this.gender,
      required this.name,
      required this.username});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
        'gender': gender,
        'email': email,
        'username': username,
      };

  static Profiles fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Profiles(
      id: json['id'],
      email: json['email'],
      gender: json['gender'],
      name: json['name'],
      username: json['username']);
}
```

Error : **Given String is empty or null**

I have defined all my textEditingControls inside textFormFields. A few hours ago I wasn't getting any errors with this code and I didn't make any changes to the code. But now I am getting this error.

Comment: add async & await in here LoginButton( onPressed: () async{await signUp();

Comment: & also check ur Firebase Database **Rules** writing is enabled or not

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: 1.  signUp 2. saving data to cloud..  which one is ok  ? Neither of them ? what is ur situation ?

Comment: This is how "" shows name, username, email values ​​into the Firestore. It auto-fills the gender value and shows the id that I selected. In error '[firebase_auth/unknown] Given String is empty or null' There is a problem in FirebaseAuth.

Comment: okka.. ur Auth SignUP is okay then ?